# Feature Selection for Regression Models in R

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I’m trying to find a Feature Selection Package in R that can be used for Regression most of the packages implement their methods for classification using a factor or class for the response variable. In particular I’m interested if there’s a method using Random Forest for that purpose. Also a good paper in this field would be helpfull.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html to start with. I am sure e.g. the `caret` package might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the `randomForest` package also does regression trees. You could start with the Breiman paper and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can use randomforest for calculating variable importance.

**I.    Mean Decrease Impurity (MDI) / Gini Importance :**
This makes use of a random forest model or a decision tree. When training a tree, it is measured by how much each feature decreases the weighted impurity in a tree. For a forest, the impurity decrease from each feature can be averaged and the features are ranked according to this measure. Here is an example of the same using R.

```
fit <- randomForest(Target ~.,importance = T,ntree = 500, data=training_data)
var.imp1 <- data.frame(importance(fit, type=2))
var.imp1$Variables <- row.names(var.imp1)
varimp1 <- var.imp1[order(var.imp1$MeanDecreaseGini,decreasing = T),]
par(mar=c(10,5,1,1)) 
giniplot <- barplot(t(varimp1[-2]/sum(varimp1[-2])),las=2,
                     cex.names=1,
                    main="Gini Impurity Index Plot")
```

And the output will look like this: [Gini Importance Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ZxB.jpg)

**II. Permutation Importance or Mean Decrease in Accuracy (MDA)** : Permutation Importance or Mean Decrease in Accuracy (MDA) is assessed for each feature by removing the association between that feature and the target. This is achieved by randomly permuting the values of the feature and measuring the resulting increase in error. The influence of the correlated features is also removed. Example in R:

```
fit <- randomForest(Target ~.,importance = T,ntree = 500, data=training_data)
var.imp1 <- data.frame(importance(fit, type=1))
var.imp1$Variables <- row.names(var.imp1)
varimp1 <- var.imp1[order(var.imp1$MeanDecreaseGini,decreasing = T),]
par(mar=c(10,5,1,1)) 
giniplot <- barplot(t(varimp1[-2]/sum(varimp1[-2])),las=2,
                     cex.names=1,
                    main="Permutation Importance Plot")
```

This two are are the ones which use Random Forest directly. There are some more easy to use metrics for variable importance calculation purpose. 'Boruta' method  and Weight of evidence (WOE) and Information Value (IV) might also be helpful.